# How can I efficiently download a large file using Go?

Tags: go, download

Is there a way to download a large file using Go that will store the content directly into a file instead of storing it all in memory before writing it to a file? Because the file is so big, storing it all in memory before writing it to a file is going to use up all the memory.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

I'll assume you mean download via http (error checks omitted for brevity):

```
import ("net/http"; "io"; "os")
...
out, err := os.Create("output.txt")
defer out.Close()
...
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
defer resp.Body.Close()
...
n, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
```

The http.Response's Body is a Reader, so you can use any functions that take a Reader, to, e.g. read a chunk at a time rather than all at once. In this specific case, `io.Copy()` does the gruntwork for you.

Comment: Note that `io.Copy` reads 32kb (maximum) from input and writes them to output, then repeats. So don't worry about memory.

Comment: how to cancel the download progress?

Comment: you can use this to cancel the download after the given timeout
```client := http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second,}
    client.Get("http://example.com/")
    ```

Answer (score 93):

A more descriptive version of [Steve M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11693049/9935654).

```
import (
    "os"
    "net/http"
    "io"
)

func downloadFile(filepath string, url string) (err error) {

  // Create the file
  out, err := os.Create(filepath)
  if err != nil  {
    return err
  }
  defer out.Close()

  // Get the data
  resp, err := http.Get(url)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()

  // Check server response
  if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    return fmt.Errorf("bad status: %s", resp.Status)
  }

  // Writer the body to file
  _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
  if err != nil  {
    return err
  }

  return nil
}
```

Comment: In my universe I implemented a DSL that needed to download a file... it was convenient to Exec() curl until I fell into some OS compat and chroot issues that I really did not want configure around because it's a sensible security model. So U replace my CURL with this code and got a 10-15x performance improvement. DUH!

Comment: @Richard glad to hear! Even though it took me some time to see this. :)

Answer (score 17):

The answer selected above using `io.Copy` is exactly what you need, but if you are interested in additional features like resuming broken downloads, auto-naming files, checksum validation or monitoring progress of multiple downloads, checkout the [grab](https://github.com/cavaliercoder/grab) package.

Comment: Could you add a code snippet to ensure that the information will not be lost if the link gets deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

I also think it's nice to have a progress indicator, especially for larger files. So I want to throw in my two cents for a solution to this problem while implementing a simple progress indicator.
(Most error handling also omitted for brevety).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    temp_path := ".tmp"
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://212.183.159.230/200MB.zip", nil)
    resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    f, _ := os.OpenFile(temp_path, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    defer f.Close()

    buf := make([]byte, 32*1024)
    var downloaded int64
    for {
        n, err := resp.Body.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Fatalf("Error while downloading: %v", err)
        }
        if n > 0 {
            f.Write(buf[:n])
            downloaded += int64(n)
            fmt.Printf("\rDownloading... %.2f%%", float64(downloaded)/float64(resp.ContentLength)*100)
        }
    }
    os.Rename(temp_path, "wordpress.zip")
}
```

To use `io.Copy` we can implement an `io.Reader` . Which probably will be the preferred approach in a real world scenario to make it reusable and easier to test. So here is the second version:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type ProgressReader struct {
    Reader io.Reader
    Size   int64
    Pos    int64
}

func (pr *ProgressReader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := pr.Reader.Read(p)
    if err == nil {
        pr.Pos += int64(n)
        fmt.Printf("\rDownloading... %.2f%%", float64(pr.Pos)/float64(pr.Size)*100)
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now().UnixMilli()
    tempPath := ".tmp"
    outPath := "200MB.zip"
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://212.183.159.230/200MB.zip", nil)
    resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        log.Fatalf("Error while downloading: %v", resp.StatusCode)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    f, _ := os.OpenFile(tempPath, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    defer f.Close()

    progressReader := &ProgressReader{
        Reader: resp.Body,
        Size:   resp.ContentLength,
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(f, progressReader); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error while downloading: %v", err)
    }

    os.Rename(tempPath, outPath)
    fmt.Println(" - Download completed!")

    fmt.Printf("Took: %.2fs\n", float64(time.Now().UnixMilli()-start)/1000)
}
```

Answer (score -8):

1. Here is a sample. https://github.com/thbar/golang-playground/blob/master/download-files.go
2. Also I give u some codes might help you.

code:

```
func HTTPDownload(uri string) ([]byte, error) {
    fmt.Printf("HTTPDownload From: %s.\n", uri)
    res, err := http.Get(uri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    d, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("ReadFile: Size of download: %d\n", len(d))
    return d, err
}

func WriteFile(dst string, d []byte) error {
    fmt.Printf("WriteFile: Size of download: %d\n", len(d))
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(dst, d, 0444)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return err
}

func DownloadToFile(uri string, dst string) {
    fmt.Printf("DownloadToFile From: %s.\n", uri)
    if d, err := HTTPDownload(uri); err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("downloaded %s.\n", uri)
        if WriteFile(dst, d) == nil {
            fmt.Printf("saved %s as %s\n", uri, dst)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example reads the entire contents into memory, with the `ioutil.ReadAll()`.  That's fine, as long as you are dealing with tiny files.

Comment: @eduncan911, but it's not fine for this question which explicitly talks about big files and not wanting to suck it all into memory.

Comment: Exactly right, that's why I commented so - for others to know as well not to use this for large files.

Comment: This is not a benign answer, and should actually be removed.  The use of ReadAll among a large pile of code is a latent problem waiting until a large file is used.  What happens is that if there are ReadAll on large files, the usually response is to go along with the high memory consumption and increased AWS bills until something fails.  By the time the problem is discovered, the bills are already high.

Comment: So what's the alternative?