# How do I download a file with a http request in go language

Tags: http, go, download

I want to download a file from an url in go lang using the go http package and save the image to disk for later display on my webpage. How do I do this?

I need to do this because I want to download images from instagram and save them to my public folder for display on my webpage.

I created an answer below for others to use the code I came up with.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692860/how-can-i-efficiently-download-a-large-file-using-go

Comment: Please provide me with some constructive comment as to how I can fix the problems that made you down vote this post.

Comment: This is a low quality question, in that it's simply asking for code to do something that would take little effort to look up in the documentation. But, since you posted it with the intent of providing the code yourself, I'll give you an up vote for effort ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some research I came up with this.

```
import (
    "os"
    "net/http"
    "io"
)

func downloadFile(filepath string, url string) (err error) {

  // Create the file
  out, err := os.Create(filepath)
  if err != nil  {
    return err
  }
  defer out.Close()

  // Get the data
  resp, err := http.Get(url)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()

  // Writer the body to file
  _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
  if err != nil  {
    return err
  }

  return nil
}
```

It works well but might need a bit of refinement for use in production.

Comment: `log.Fatal` calls `os.Exit`, so the panics do nothing (plus, you generally shouldn't panic over basic errors). You're not closing the response body (please read the [http package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)), which will leak connections. There's no reason to buffer the entire file in memory, you can copy the download directly to an open file.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will check it out. I'm quite new to go. For me there is no reason not to download the whole file as I know the file size. I will fix the leak and the logs though. Please up vote if your happy with the new result.

Comment: If you want to point me in the right direction with the buffering issue I would be happy. @JimB

Comment: I fixed the issues. Thanks! :D

Comment: don't defer before checking your errors, since the value you have may not be valid and can panic.

Comment: Thanks! What will happen if a panic is triggered? Don't I want the defers to run then?

Comment: @PabloKarlsson: You don't want the defer to run if the result was nil, because that's where it's going to panic. A panic is usually a mistake in your code, you shouldn't see them at all.

Comment: @JimB But you agree with the current version or do you think there are still some flaws?

Comment: This latest version OK.