# Is there a way to reach .pdf files over the network with docconv?

Tags: pdf, go

I'm starting to use Golang and I'm wondering if there is a way to get an online ***.pdf*** file and extract all the text that is inside it. At this moment I was making some tests with the library [docconv](https://github.com/sajari/docconv) and it works beautiful with local files but when I try to reach an online file I just can't get it, here is what I had tried

**First Try**

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sajari/docconv"
    "github.com/sajari/docconv/client"
)

func main(){
    c := client.New()
    res, err := client.ConvertPath(c, "some online url")        

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil
    }

    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

I'm also look up to other libraries like [yob/pdfreader](https://github.com/yob/pdfreader) and [rsc/pdf](https://github.com/rsc/pdf) but still not working, and locally the best of that libraries is **docconv**

Any ideas or help to reach the goal is truly welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: So your question is whether the docconv library has built-in file downloading? What did the documentation tell you?

Comment: In the docs, `client.New()` says it "Create a new client, using the default endpoint (localhost:8888)"

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [code](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/sajari/docconv/-/blob/client/client.go) of the client package seems like it is trying to comunicate with a remote docconv server. For your purpose, you have to download a the file in your local, and then use the library as you have been doing. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845770/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-a-http-request-in-go-language) you can see an example of how to download the file with an http client.