# upload large file - Error VirtualAlloc of x bytes failed with errno=1455 fatal error: out of memory

Tags: go

I have 10GB large file that I'm trying to upload with multipart/form-data in Go via Postman. Since I don't know much how file upload works in Go, I found tutorial on YouTube.

File upload works fine with smaller files, but on larger files always crashing with message: "runtime: VirtualAlloc of 9193373696 bytes failed with errno=1455
fatal error: out of memory". Here's the code I'm trying to make work:

```
    err := r.ParseMultipartForm(500 << 20)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    }

    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    }

    fmt.Fprintln(w, handler.Filename)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, handler.Size)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, handler.Header.Get("Content-type"))

    defer file.Close()

    saveLocation := "C:\\Users\\Pc\\go\\src\\github.com\\test\\uptest"
    tempFile, err := ioutil.TempFile(saveLocation, "upload")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    }

    defer tempFile.Close()

    fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    }
    tempFile.Write(fileBytes)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I efficiently download a large file using Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692860/how-can-i-efficiently-download-a-large-file-using-go)

Comment: Realise that the proposed duplicate relates to downloading rather than uploading but the base issue and solution is the same (use `io.copy` rather than doing a `ReadAll` & `Write` which requires that you hold the file in memory).

Comment: If you upload a large file,  you can  split it into lots of small files; Upload files concurrently;  And merge them in the server side.

Comment: @Brits This is for download file to server or PC. I needed to upload file to server. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Brits I tried many other solutions, and found that uploading file makes copy in temp directory, but didn't know how to get that copy.

Comment: @MiffaYoung I know that, but I didn't know how to put that in my code.  I know that file is hold in memory. Since I have only 8GB of ram, and file is 10GB, I need to store chunks of data in temp file on disk, because my PC don't have enough memory to store whole file. But I didn't know how to write that in my code. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ParseMultipartForm()` will require you to provide max memory allocation for temporarily store the uploaded file. If your file size is big (and it's bigger than the number of memory you allocated) then it's bad news for your memory resource.

> From doc:
> ParseMultipartForm parses a request body as multipart/form-data. The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes of its file parts are stored in memory, with the remainder stored on disk in temporary files. ParseMultipartForm calls ParseForm if necessary. After one call to ParseMultipartForm, subsequent calls have no effect.

Based on your error message, we can tell that the root cause of your issue is due to the uploaded file is larger than the memory you allocated, which is `500 << 20`.

For handling big file upload, I suggest to take a look at `MultipartReader()` instead.

> From doc:
> MultipartReader returns a MIME multipart reader if this is a multipart/form-data or a multipart/mixed POST request, else returns nil and an error. Use this function instead of ParseMultipartForm to process the request body as a stream.

It's way faster approach and won't consume too much resource, it's because we will have the advantage of directly store the body (which is a stream data) into the destination file using `io.Copy()`, instead of writing it into temporarily storage first.

A simple usage example of `MultipartReader()`:

```golang
reader, err := r.MultipartReader()
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

for {
    part, err := reader.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    fmt.Println(part.FileName()) // prints file name
    fmt.Println(part.FormName()) // prints form key, in yor case it's "file"
    
    saveLocation := "C:\\Users\\Pc\\go\\src\\github.com\\test\\uptest"
    dst, err := os.Create(saveLocation)
    if dst != nil {
        defer dst.Close()
    }
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(dst, part); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

Reference: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm

Comment: Thank you so much kind person. Your code is what I needed and works like a charm. I would like to award you with the highest honor I can bestow!

Comment: I'm happy to help :)